# jquery - show textbox when checkbox checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this form

```
<form action="">
  <div id="opwp_woo_tickets">
    <input type="checkbox" class="maxtickets_enable_cb" name="opwp_wootickets[tickets][0][enable]">
    <div class="max_tickets">
        <input type="text" name="opwp_wootickets[tickets][0][maxtickets]">
    </div>

    <input type="checkbox" class="maxtickets_enable_cb" name="opwp_wootickets[tickets][1][enable]">
    <div class="max_tickets">
        <input type="text" name="opwp_wootickets[tickets][1][maxtickets]">
    </div>

    <input type="checkbox" class="maxtickets_enable_cb" name="opwp_wootickets[tickets][2][enable]">
    <div class="max_tickets">
        <input type="text" name="opwp_wootickets[tickets][2][maxtickets]">
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

As of now, I'm using this jquery code to show textbox when checkbox checked.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
   $('input.maxtickets_enable_cb').change(function(){
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) $('div.max_tickets').show();
        else $('div.max_tickets').hide();
    }).change();
});
```

It works fine, but it shows all textboxes when checked.

Can someone help me to fix it?

Here is the demo of my problem.

http://codepen.io/mistergiri/pen/spBhD

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As your dividers are placed next to your checkboxes, you simply need to use [jQuery's `next()` method](http://api.jquery.com/next/) to select the correct elements:

```
if ($(this).is(':checked'))
    $(this).next('div.max_tickets').show();
else
    $(this).next('div.max_tickets').hide();
```

[**Updated Codepen demo**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GIuwc).

From the documentation (linked above), the `next()` method selects:

> *...the immediately following sibling of each element in the set of matched elements. If a selector is provided, it retrieves the next sibling only if it matches that selector.*

Here we're selecting the next `div.max_tickets` element. However in your case just using `next()` with no parameters would suffice.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming markup will stay in same order can use `next()`

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    $('input.maxtickets_enable_cb').change(function(){
                $(this).next()[ this.checked ? 'show' : 'hide']();  
    }).change();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try selecting the next element only?

change:

```
if ($(this).is(':checked')) $('div.max_tickets').show();
```

to:

```
if ($(this).is(':checked')) $(this).next('div.max_tickets').show();
```

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
if ($(this).is(':checked')) $('div.max_tickets').show();
```

To:

```
if ($(this).is(':checked')) $(this).next('div.max_tickets').show();
```

[jsFiddle example here](http://jsfiddle.net/NmByg/)

Answer (score 1):

While you may need a JavaScript solution for other reasons, it's worth noting that this can be achieved with pure CSS:

```css
input + div.max_tickets {
    display: none;
}

input:checked + div.max_tickets {
    display: block;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/NrUyr/).

Or, with jQuery, the simplest approach seems to be:

```
// binds the change event-handler to all inputs of type="checkbox"
$('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function(){
    /* finds the next element with the class 'max_tickets',
       shows the div if the checkbox is checked,
       hides it if the checkbox is not checked:
    */
    $(this).next('.max_tickets').toggle(this.checked);
// triggers the change-event on page-load, to show/hide as appropriate:
}).change();
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/NrUyr/1/).

Reference:

- CSS:

  - [`:checked` pseudo-class](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#checked).
- jQuery:

  - [`change()`](http://api.jquery.com/change/).
  - [`next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next/).
  - [`toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/).

Answer (score 1):

Put a div across your checkbox and text box

```
<form action="">
<div id="opwp_woo_tickets">
<div>
    <input type="checkbox" class="maxtickets_enable_cb" name="opwp_wootickets[tickets][0][enable]">
    <div class="max_tickets">
        <input type="text" name="opwp_wootickets[tickets][0][maxtickets]">
    </div>
</div>
<div>
    <input type="checkbox" class="maxtickets_enable_cb" name="opwp_wootickets[tickets][1][enable]">
    <div class="max_tickets">
        <input type="text" name="opwp_wootickets[tickets][1][maxtickets]">
    </div>
</div>
<div>
    <input type="checkbox" class="maxtickets_enable_cb" name="opwp_wootickets[tickets][2][enable]">
    <div class="max_tickets">
        <input type="text" name="opwp_wootickets[tickets][2][maxtickets]">
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</form>
```

and replace your jquery code with this one below,

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
   $('input.maxtickets_enable_cb').change(function(){
       if ($(this).is(':checked')) $(this).parent().children('div.max_tickets').show();
       else $(this).parent().children('div.max_tickets').hide();
   }).change();
});
```

I have tested it and it works.

Answer (score -1):

```
protected void EnableTextBox()
{
    int count = int.Parse(GridView1.Rows.Count.ToString());

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].FindControl("CheckBox1");
        CheckBox cb1 = (CheckBox)GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].FindControl("CheckBox2");
        CheckBox cb2 = (CheckBox)GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].FindControl("CheckBox3");
        TextBox tb = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[4].FindControl("txtration");
        TextBox tb1 = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[5].FindControl("txtjob");
        TextBox tb2 = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[6].FindControl("txtaadhar");            

        if (cb.Checked == true)
        {
            tb.Visible = true;               
        }
        else
        {
            tb.Visible = false;    
        }

        if (cb1.Checked == true)
        {
            tb1.Visible = true;                
        }
        else
        {
            tb1.Visible = false;              
        }

        if (cb2.Checked == true)
        {
            tb2.Visible = true;               
        }
        else
        {
            tb2.Visible = false;
        }
    }
}

protected void CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    EnableTextBox();
}
```