# JQuery - enable 4 text-boxes at once if 1 checkbox is checked

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, checkbox

I have search before I post, but I only found questions and solutions that is showing ONE textbox if ONE checkbox is checked as in: [jquery - show textbox when checkbox checked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19670323/jquery-show-textbox-when-checkbox-checked)

But my form is different

```
<form method="post" action="actionhere">
<div id='clone_me'>
    <?php 
    for($i=1; $i<=5;$i++) {
        ?>
      <div>
        <span id="title">Line <?php echo $i;?></span>

        <input type='checkbox' name='ck_<?php echo $i;?>'/>
        <input type='text' class='tx<?php echo $i;?>' name='tx[<?php echo $i;?>][]'/>
        <input type='text' class='tx<?php echo $i;?>' name='tx[<?php echo $i;?>][]'/>
        <input type='text' class='tx<?php echo $i;?>' name='tx[<?php echo $i;?>][]'/>
        <input type='text' class='tx<?php echo $i;?>' name='tx[<?php echo $i;?>][]'/>
     </div>
    <?php } ?>
</div>
<input type='submit' name='submit' value='Submit'/>
<input type="button" value="Add row" class="addrow" />
</form>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.addrow').click(function(){                
       var n= $("#clone_me>div").length;
       var new_n=n+1;              
       var new_line= $('#clone_me div:first').clone().append();                
       $("span#title", new_line).text("Line "+new_n+" ");
      //since I clone the 1st <div> therefore the cloned id must be 'ck_1', so changed it to latest id      
   $("input#ck_1", new_line).attr("name", "ck_"+new_n);
   $("input#ck_1", new_line).attr("id", "ck_"+new_n);           
   $("input.tx1", new_line).attr("name", "tx["+new_n+"][]");
       $("input.tx1", new_line).attr("class", "tx"+new_n);
       new_line.appendTo('#clone_me');

    });
});
</script>
```

As you can see from the code, I have a form which by default will have 5 sets of 1-checkbox-4-textbox, and user is allowed to add new set by clicking 'add row' button (which jquery will do clone).

How can I make the 4 textbox enabled once the correspond checkbox is checked? I'm not using hide() or show(). I want the user knows the textbox are there, but is disabled until user tick the checkbox.

```
if ($("#ck_4").is(":checked")) {
            $("input#tx4).attr("readonly", false); //or enabled
```

I thought it will be something like that, but since user can dynamically add how many rows as he wants, how can I achieve it?

http://jsfiddle.net/aLw3T/2/

Comment: Can you setup a jsbin/fiddle ?

Comment: @PatsyIssa Hi i edited my post and post the jsfiddle link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as the input fields are siblings to the checkbox you can use following jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('form').on('click', 'input[type=checkbox]', function(e) {
    var checkbox = $(this);
    checkbox.closest('.row').find('input[type=text]').prop('disabled',!checkbox.is(':checked')); 
  });
});
```

if you have multiple forms, change the selector used for binding of the click event.

e.g. `$('form.my_form').on...`

see example: http://codepen.io/lchngr/pen/zhasg/

Comment: Hi thanks, it works as you said -if the fields are sibling, but is it impossible if some input field is inside a div tag after the checkbox? I have like, a checkbox-textbox-div-dropdownbox-end_div

Comment: also, the script work for those original rows, but it doesn't work for cloned object

Comment: i updated the pen. it can now handle input fields nested under divs

Comment: hi, thanks. you'd better change the answer here so I can mark it as answer..?
thanks!

Answer (score 1):

first give your checkbox a data attribute like this

```
<input type='checkbox' data-id="<?php echo $i;?>" name='ck_<?php echo $i;?>'/>
```

after this create following javascript code to handle your input/textarea fields

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function () {
        var self = $(this);
        var checkboxId = self.data('id');
        var checkboxChecked = self.is(":checked");

        /* jQuery < 1.9 */
        if (checkboxChecked) {
            $('.tx' + checkboxId).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        } else {
            $('.tx' + checkboxId).removeAttr('disabled');
        }

        /* jQuery 1.9+ */
        $('.tx' + checkboxId).prop('disabled', checkboxChecked);
    });
});
```

Comment: hi, what if I have multiple form inside 1 page? each form has similar format, but the checkbox id for each form is different. let's assume for form 1>ck_1|ck_2|ck_3, form2>ck2_1|ck2_2|etc

Comment: because of that you should be use this attribute `data-id="<?php echo $i;?>"`

Comment: Hi, could you please check what I did wrong, i can't seem to make it work? I put it: http://jsfiddle.net/aLw3T/2/

Comment: try this ;) because you use input fields, not textarea you must use "disable" atttribute http://jsfiddle.net/aLw3T/3/

Comment: hi thanks, but it doesn't work (or my clone code is wrong) for cloned objects...?

Comment: also, I actually want the textbox are disabled by default, and only enabled them if checkbox is ticked

Comment: here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/x4AA9/ fork of your fiddle. if you clone the html elements you have no events binded on them. i changed the code to use a delegated event on the form element.